# Virtual Trim of MediaElement

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement

I have both a 20 second audio file and a 60 second video file. I only want to include these once, but need different start/end times for them in various `<MediaElement>`s.

For example, on my page one I need the seconds 2-13 of the audio file and on page two I need the first 10 seconds (0-9). On page three I need seconds 12-18. I'd really prefer not to have 3 different audio files, just a set of start/end values for the portion of audio/video file.

I see `.Position` for a start time, but what about an end time that doesn't have to hook an event to stop itself? Also, I'm not sure what the XAML for `.Position` would look like as there is no sample of that on MSDN.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a great way to do this on this thread: [Silverlight: Expose audio with specific start and stop times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146765/silverlight-expose-audio-with-specific-start-and-stop-times)